# Android - Create and start Activities based on server response (JSON)

Tags: android, json, android-activity

I have a JSON response from the server, like this:

```
{
    "types": [
                {
                    "type_name": "ACTIVITY_TITLE_1",    
                    //  ... other Activity realted data
                },
                {
                    "type_name": "ACTIVITY_TITLE_2",    
                    //  ... other Activity realted data
                }
                // ... and who knows how many more other type object...
             ]
}
```

I get this JSON from a background service, and after I saved that to a DB, my SplashScreen should generate activities from this JSON.

So I need to create a new Activity for every 'type' what I get from the server, and automatically start them one after the other.
Every Activity is exacty the same (so I instantiate the same class), just the content differs (what I get from the JSON).
The only problem is, that I don't know how many 'types' I'm gonna get, so how many Activity I need to create, and I can't use Fragments (what would be an easy solution), beacause I have to use Fragments in these Activites.

What is the best design approach for this?

From the first activity (kind of a long 'splash screen') I should start the ACTIVITY_TITLE_1 activity with startActivityForResult(), and when I'm done I start the ACTIVITY_TITLE_2 from that 'splash screen'?

Or I should start the ACTIVITY_TITLE_2 activity from the ACTIVITY_TITLE_1, and inside that ACTIVITY_TITLE_1 get the information somehow from the DB, that there are more activities based on the JSON array waiting for the start, and start the next one from there?

Neither looks too 'professional' solution for me...  :D

**EDIT**:
*I'm developing kind of a simple "dashboard", and I have new data from the server in every 10 minutes in a JSON form like above. So I only need to display the latest JSON response, which is a "blueprint" for activities, and show them automatically one after the other... In the example above, there will be 2 activities automatically alternating in a few seconds... But if I get a server response 30 minutes later, which contains 3 activites (types), than I need to generate and show 3 one after the other. Always based on the last JSON response.
So, I'm gonna save immediately to DB my JSON response, but in the next automatic "round", I'll have to show 3 activities now. So I need to generate and start activites what I create on the fly... :D*

Comment: " I can't use Fragments (what would be an easy solution), beacause I have to use Fragments in these Activites." 

There exists a thing called child fragments ( fragment inside a fragment )

Answer (score 0):

Ok . You don't need to create new activity foreach json response . Just hold one activity and than load the content depending on the response you get. Just from your splash screen which is an Activity/Fragment for itself send data to a new Activity you will generate . If you need to save all your responses hold a local database (Sqlite, Realm or whatever) and just change the content depending on the value that you need .

Comment: Probably I was not detailed enough.
I'm developing kind of a simple "dashboard", and I have new data from the server in every 10 minutes in a JSON form like above.

So I only need to display the latest JSON response, which is a "blueprint" for activities, and show them automatically one after the other...
In the example above, there will be 2 activities automatically alternating in a few seconds...
But if I get a server response 30 minutes later, which contains 3 activites (types), than I need to generate and show 3 one after the other. Always based on the last JSON response.

Comment: So, I'm gonna save immediately to DB my JSON response, but in the next automatic "round", I'll have to show 3 activities now. So I need to generate and start activites what I create on the fly...  :D

Comment: The problem is more complicated, but I tried to simplify the basis of the problem. I need to instantiate and alternate automatically the same activity based on external input.
I'm only interested about the "architecture design" what I should use.
My problem isn't just that to change the title and the list inside the activity. I have the reason why I need to create new Activity one after the other.

But the question is: what is the optimal/ideal solution?  :)